# Exec into kubernetes pod in a particular directory

Tags: bash, kubernetes

How do I make this work?

```
[alan@stormfather-0be642-default-1 ~]$ kubectl exec -it my-pod-0 -- bash -c "/bin/bash && cd /tmp"
[root@my-pod-0 /]# pwd
/
```

Comment: Just to add some insight into your issue. The reason you can't cd to the directory after executing (entering) the shell like that (with`&& cd...`) is because `&&` waits for the process that comes before it to exit. In this case it will wait for your `/vin/bash` shell to exit, then cd. `&&` doesn't run a command *into* your shell, that's what `bash -c [command]` is for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change directory first and then sh into it.

```
kubectl exec -it my-pod-0 -- bash -c "cd /tmp && /bin/bash"
```

Comment: I tried something similar `kubectl exec -it <podname> -- bash -c "cd /app && ls"` and got the error `OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "bash": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
command terminated with exit code 126`

Answer (score 1):

Mohsin Amjad's answer is both simple and correct, if you are getting the

> ..."bash": executable file not found in $PATH...

error, this just means the container inside the pod does not have bash installed, instead try sh or other shells. I.e. something like:

```
kubectl exec -it my-pod-0 -- sh -c "cd /tmp && echo $0 $SHELL"
```